# Points in d3d11

Tags: directx11, point-cloud

D3D10/D3D11 drops support for point primitives. I'm trying to render a set of points for quick and dirty debug, any suggestions/quick hacks for getting large size points to show up in D3D11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, hold on, there's still [D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTLIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476189(VS.85).aspx), not sure why I was under the impression D3D11 didn't support point primitives.

Comment: Probably because I hear they dropped _point spriting_

Comment: And also there's no `D3D11_FILL_POINTS` [listed in the fillmode enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476131(VS.85).aspx)